# Will I receive a mage armor perk if I cast a flesh spell before turning into a Vampire Lord?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

As you all know you are not wearing armor when in the Vampire Lord form. And, the mage armor perk in the alteration tree will improve flesh spells.

I just want to know: If I am wearing heavy armor, then I cast a flesh spell, and, then I turn into a Vampire Lord. Will the mage armor perk be active since I am casting the spell wearing armor even though, afterward, I am not?

Comment: I gotta say, I know nothing about Skyrim, so I had to read the title like 5 times :P

Comment: @Robotnik lol I misread it too, but I corrected my answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes you do.

This is pretty easy to confirm.  You can use the console command **player.getav damageresist** to see your armor rating without having access to the inventory page:

My vampire lord's armor rating was 325 before casting stoneflesh (which is supposed to be a 60 point armor boost), and after casting it it is now 505 (which is a gain of 180 due to mage armor x3 effect).  My normal armor rating went from 492-552 so I didn't gain any perk effects while not in vampire lord form.

[image: Vampire lord armor rating after casting stoneflesh]

Now, considering the spell effect will wears off after a short time, its not too useful for the 3 perk points you must spend, but if you have a mod such as [Invested Magic](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/11397) it becomes much more useful.